# Scala concatenate lists with foldRight

Tags: scala

I making function of list to list adding.

I can't understand why it's doesn't working

```
def lconcat(l: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
    return l.foldRight(1)((x:List[Int], y:List[Int]) => x ++ y)
  }
```

and I call function like

```
println(lconcat(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))))
```

I want result like `List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Comment: `l.foldRight(1)` this says that the return of the whole operation will be an `Int`, you probably want `l.foldRight(List.empty[Int])` instead.

Comment: I doesn't know that what (1) mean, I learn thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return List of Integers, the parameter of `foldRight` should be an empty list that the input lists will be concatenated to it.

Your code should be:

```
  def lconcat(l: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
    l.foldRight(List.empty[Int])((x:List[Int], y: List[Int]) => {
      x ++ y
    })
  }
```

Comment: I see I learn empty lists importance. Thanks to you

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer if it helped you